# Adjust fan speed via Fancontrol according to hard disk temperature (Hddtemp)

Tags: linux, scripting, hard-disk, temperature, fan

How can I adjust fan speed according to hard drive temperature via Fancontrol?

Comment: I don't know anything about fancontrol, but  supports HDD temp; you could try asking for the feature or giving it a shot yourself. The easiest solution at hand seems to be to write a daemon (or just a shell script ran at boot) script that queries the disk temperature regularly and then sends commands to fancontrol. Also, a [little googling](https://github.com/desbma/hddfancontrol) can go a long way.

Comment: How does hddfancontrol malfunction? Did you install fancontrol directly from that page or as part of the lm_sensors package? I could write for you a shell script, but I use neither fancontrol nor hddtemp; I'm not sure how their outputs are structured. If you have any experience with using the shell so far, see if you can give it a crack -- check out https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/ https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/ and https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: hddfancontrol is not in root's [$PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html). What directory is it installed in? Running `which hddfancontrol` as your normal user might yield the information you're looking for; it needs to be somewhere like /usr/local/bin. If you cannot find it, try running `locate hddfancontrol` or `find / -iname *hddfancontrol*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89425/discussion-between-matthew-wai-and-kenneth-b-jensen).

Comment: I have given the best advice I can in the chat.

Comment: FAO other reviewers (like me) who come across this question in the Review queues: this question has a comprehensive and detailed self-answer.

Comment: FAO: "**hddfancontrol**" is simply useless on my Linux. The script I found is simple and useful. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a simple script to control fan speed according to hard drive temperature via **[Fancontrol](https://pkgs.org/download/fancontrol)**, **[Hddtemp](https://pkgs.org/download/hddtemp)**, and **[Lm-sensors](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=lm_sensors)**. In the following script, “**/dev/sda**” is the hard disk to be monitored, and “**/Fancontrol/Hddtemp**” is the output file to be read by Fancontrol. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> **+** <kbd>Alt</kbd> **+** <kbd>T</kbd> to open Terminal and run the following command to check whether “**/dev/sda**” is the correct one:

> sudo hddtemp /dev/sd[a-z]

Use only the one supported by Hddtemp, which will display the temperature rather than “S.M.A.R.T. not available”. 
Replace “**/dev/sda**” with the correct one in the script if necessary. 
If you have not yet configured Fancontrol, see **[this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fan_speed_control)**, **[this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/)**, and **[this page](http://tuxtweaks.com/2008/08/how-to-control-fan-speeds-in-ubuntu/)** and run the following commands one by one (restart Linux after running the first one):

> sudo sensors-detect 
>   watch sensors 
>   sudo pwmconfig 
>   sudo service fancontrol start

Then, go through the procedure below: 
(1) Run the following command to create a script file.

> sudo mkdir -p "/Fancontrol/" & sudo xed /Fancontrol/HDD_temp

(2) Copy the following script into the file and save it.

```
#!/bin/bash
File=/Fancontrol/Hddtemp
while true
do 
temperature=$(sudo hddtemp -n /dev/sda)
echo $(($temperature * 1000)) > "$File"
sleep 30 
done
```

(3) Run the following command to make it executable.

> sudo chmod +x /Fancontrol/HDD_temp

(4) Run the following command to create a service file.

> sudo xed /lib/systemd/system/HDD_temp.service

(5) Copy the following lines into the file and save it.

> [Service]
>   
>   ExecStart=/Fancontrol/HDD_temp
>   
>   [Install]
>   
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

(6) Run the following commands one by one:

> sudo chmod 664 /lib/systemd/system/HDD_temp.service
>   
>   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
>   
>   sudo systemctl start HDD_temp.service
>   
>   sudo systemctl enable HDD_temp.service

Then, the script “**HDD_temp**” will be run as a system service at Linux startup. 

(7) Run the following command to edit “**fancontrol**”, the configuration file.

> sudo xed /etc/fancontrol

Find the line that begins with “**FCTEMPS**”. For example:

> FCTEMPS=hwmon1/pwm1=hwmon1/temp1_input

On that line, “**hwmon1/temp1_input**” is the temperature (e.g. the chipset temperature) currently read by Fancontrol. Replace it with “**/Fancontrol/Hddtemp**”, and the line will become:

> FCTEMPS=hwmon1/pwm1=/Fancontrol/Hddtemp

Save the file and run the following command to restart Fancontrol.

> sudo service fancontrol restart

Then, the fan controlled by “**hwmon1/pwm1**” will respond to “**/Fancontrol/Hddtemp**”, the hard disk temperature. Note that "HDD_temp" and "Hddtemp" are the script file and output file respectively. Don't confuse them.

Comment: After Ctrl+Alt+T I bet you need to *install* fancontrol and lm-sensors :-p

Comment: In my answer, "Fancontrol", "Hddtemp", and "Lm-sensors" are hypertext links to their download pages. I assume readers know how to install them.

Answer (score 2):

I found Mathew Wai's answer really good, but I ran into some issues with drives sleeping and temperature data corruption.  This has been stable for me:

```
FILE=/tmp/Hddtemp
while true
do
    temperature=$(hddtemp -n /dev/sdc 2>/dev/null)
    # Set base temp if we got nothing in stdout, this mean we are asleep
    if [ "$temperature" == "" ]; then temperature=30; fi
    # Get a tempfile to write out temp
    NEW=$(mktemp /tmp/Hddtemp.XXXX)
    echo $(($temperature * 1000)) > $NEW
    # Handle case of initial/clean run
    if [ -e $FILE ]; then
        CLEAN="rm -f $(readlink -f $FILE)"
    fi
    # Atomic symlink replacement
    ln -s $NEW $FILE.lnk
    mv -T $FILE.lnk $FILE
    # Clean old link, if it existed
    $CLEAN
    sleep 30
done
```

Given that hddtemp is going [away](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=343998) in the next Debian release, I've changed mine to use "drivetemp", which can be read from sensors so I'll replace:

```
    temperature=$(hddtemp -n /dev/sdc 2>/dev/null)
```

with

```
    temperature=$(sensors -A drivetemp-scsi-5-0|grep temp1|tr -s ' '|cut -d '+' -f 2|cut -d '.' -f1;)
```

I have found this new sensors method stable for quite a while.