# How do I use Crontab to open a file at Linux startup only on a specific date?

Tags: linux-mint, cron, reboot

```
matthew@matthew-pc:~$ crontab -l 
[...]
@reboot 1 5 * sleep 10s && export DISPLAY=:0 && xdg-open ~/@/Testing.jpg
```

"Testing.jpg" was not opened at Linux startup on May 1. 
How can I use Crontab to open a file at Linux startup on a specific date, e.g. May 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix a schedule with `@reboot` - `cron` doesn't support that.

If you want to open a file at Linux startup on a specific date, do this:

1. Write a script (chkdate.sh) that checks the date for a match to (for example) May 2
2. Use the `@reboot` spec in `cron` to run `chkdate.sh`

> [EDIT: re `chkdate.sh`, a script to check today's date against a specific date]:

You could write a [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) script to accomplish this. The `date` function in `bash` will return today's date. Having that, you only need then to test today's date against the specific date, and take the desired action. Here's one way to approach this:

> NOTE: I use a Debian-based Linux distribution, so what follows reflects that. Your system may vary somewhat.

1. Use the `date` function: Open a "terminal window", or simply get the command prompt on your system. At the command prompt (`$` in my case), type `date +%Y-%m-%d`:

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d
2019-05-02
$
```

2. Specify the `date` format needed: `date` can provide its output in a variety of different formats. In the example above, the format is "Year-month-day". If you are interested only in the month and day, then the command would be: `date +%m-%d`:

```
$ date +%m-%d
05-02
$
```

3. Regardless of the format you need, you must learn to use the system documentation. To learn how to instruct `date` to provide its output in the format you need, you will need to read its documentation:

```
$ man date
...
q
$
```

Note that the single character `q` will close the `man` page.

4. Once you've decided on the format of the `date` output, you can begin to write the script `chkdate.sh`. Let's create the file, and open it in an easy-to-use text editor:

```
$ nano ~/chkdate.sh
...
```

You may begin entering your script; for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOMEDAY="05-02"
TODAY=`date +%m-%d`
if [ $TODAY == $SOMEDAY ]
then 
   echo "Today is the day!"
else
   echo "Today is NOT the day."
fi
```

Now, save the file `^o`, and exit the `nano` editor `^x`.

5. You will need to set the file permissions to make the script executable, and you may then run it:

```
$ chmod 755 ~/chkdate.sh
$ ~/chkdate.sh 
Today is the day!
$
```

Because today is May 2<sup>nd</sup>, the `then` condition of the `if` statement is executed (`echo "Today is the day!"`). On any other day of the year, the `else` statement would be executed. Also note that it is not necessary to have an `else` condition - you may simply omit it if you don't need it.

6. Assuming this executes, you can modify the script to replace the `echo ...` command(s) with the command(s) you want to use.

Comment: I don't know how to write `chkdate.sh`. Please help.

Comment: @MatthewWai: This is not a script-writing service, but I'll help you. What programming languages do you work in - bash, Python, C...? In bash, you could use the `date` function; I've edited my answer, and added a bit to get you started.

Comment: Many thanks to Seamus, who has helped me with my second bash script. My first bash script is [**this**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504680/332937). Hopefully, I will soon learn the third one.

Comment: @MatthewWai: This was probably more than you needed. I incorrectly assumed you had less experience than you obviously do. A couple of other points: 1) The `at` package may provide another solution, and 2) `systemd` has an advantage over the `@reboot` facility in `cron`.

Comment: On my Linux Mint, **echo "Today is the day!"** brings up nothing, while **zenity --info --text="Today is the day!"** brings up a message box.

Comment: @MatthewWai: Not a Mint user, but `zenity` sounds like a GUI/GTK thing. You need a `bash` prompt for `echo` to work. If you can't open a terminal window, [take a look at this for possible pointers.](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/100)